# Apache Commons copyURLToFile - possible to stop copying?

Tags: java, apache-commons

Is it possible to interrupt downloading with org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile?

I've got separate Thread with one line

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(url), targetFile);
```

I want to stop downloading immediately from outside.

Thank you!

```
threadFetch = new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        isFetching = true;
                        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(url), targetFile);
                        isFetching = false;
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(YoutubeMovieLink.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            };
            threadFetch.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think copyURLToFile() supports this, you probably need to implement block-wise read from the inputstream and write to the file, then you can check between each block if copying should be stopped. BLOCK_SIZE is a tunable depending on the expected download size and how fast it should react on the stop-signal.

I.e. something like the following (might be buggy, did not actually run it):

```
InputStream input = new URL(url).getInputStream();
try {
OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputSteam(new FileOutputStream(targetFile));
 try {
 byte[] block[BLOCK_SIZE];
 while(!input.isEof()) {
    if(shouldBeCancelled) {
        System.out.println("Stopped!");
        break;
    }

    // read block
    int i = input.read(block);
    if(i == -1) {
         break;
    }

    // write block
    output.write(block);
 }
} finally {
   output.close();
} finally {
   input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure like many more other methods, this command has no timeout option.

I also run this kind of problem in many situations, so I created a little utility method to run a command with timeout, maybe it can help you:

```
public static <T> T runWithTimeout(Callable<T> task, int timeout) throws Exception{
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<T> future = executor.submit(task);
    T result = future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    executor.shutdown();
    return result;
}
```